# Recycle bitmap in fragment class

Tags: android, bitmap, android-fragments, android-viewpager

In my app I am using `ViewPager` and fragments for swiping. In my fragment class, in `onDestroyView()`, I am recycling the bitmap object that i am using:

```
@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    if (Bitmapm != null) {
        if (!Bitmapm.isRecycled()) {
            Bitmapm.recycle();
            System.out.println("recyc333 " + Bitmapm.isRecycled());
        }
    }
    super.onDestroyView();
}
```

But here my problem is that `onDestroyView()` is not called at all after swipe. It's called only after pressing back button. So is there any other way to recycle bitmap?

Comment: if you swipe more than a fragment inside the ViewPager the onDestroyView should be invoked.

Comment: yaa it should but in my case i don't know why it is not calling.i put there log message also but didn't get any message in logcat.so is there any other life cycle method where i will recycle bitmap?

Comment: The pager adapter extends from `FragmentPagerAdapter` or `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`?

Comment: fragmentStatePagerAdapter